# Object won't move when I apply velocity to it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I'm making an object point towards another one, and try to move it with a change in velocity, the object just moves backward a little bit.
My Code:

```
public Rigidbody riggy;
public float speed = 100f;
public float maxSpeed = 100f;
Vector3 direction;
void Start()
{
    Transform player = GameObject.Find("Von").transform;
    StartCoroutine(Chase(0, player.transform));
}
void Update()
{
    riggy.velocity = transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime; //applies velocity
}
IEnumerator Chase(float speed, Transform target) {
    while (transform.position != target.position) {
        var direction = (target.position - transform.position); //finds the direction of Von
        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction); // finds the rotation that the object has to move
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, target.transform.position, Color.green);
        transform.rotation = rotation; // moves the object
        yield return null; 
    }
}
```

A video:
https://youtu.be/1I5bSvLBCuQ

Comment: Do **not** multiply the speed by `Time.deltaTime`. When in `Update` all that does is reduce the speed applied by your framerate. Either increase your speed or remove the `Time.deltaTime`. It is effectively taking your current speed and reducing it to 1/60 of the original speed.

Comment: I did that but the object still moves backwards.

Comment: Your speed is a public field, in the inspector is it a good value? Are you changing the velocity anywhere else?

Comment: I don't change the velocity anywhere else, and for some reason when I set the speed, it doesn't change anything. (I added a video btw)

Comment: All that work. Why not have riggt lookat the chase ovject and just apply forward force

Comment: Is there a special reason why you do one thing in `Update` and the other in a Coroutine? Also when using a `Rigidbody` don't set anything via the `Transform` rather use `riggy.rotation` or `riggy.MoveRotation` instead

Comment: I do one thing in update and one thing in a Couroutine for no real reason, but it might be useful if I want to make a whole new enemy. I tried adding forward force, but to no avail.

Comment: try riggy.transform.position = transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;

Comment: I did what you wrote Art Zolina III, but I added the transform.position to the second part, and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your script should work, so it's fault of your scene setup. Video does not show much about how your scene is made, so I can just list some possible errors:

- Ensure component speed value is not negative and large enough
- Rigidbody reference can be on wrong object or setup (structure) invalid
- Object "Von" is not the object you want or it's origin point is somewhere else than you think
- Possible there is rigidbody inside other rigidbody and this creates weird results

**Additional notes**:
There is no need to make additional coroutine, you could put everything inside Update and don't worry about "it might be useful if I want to make a whole new enemy", unless it gonna happen for sure. Physics manipulation should be done in FixedUpdate.
Depending what you want to do you might not need rigidbody or make them kinematic, but in the case above you are directly controlling velocity, so it would be good if you read [bunny's answer here](http://answers.unity.com/answers/802667/view.html).
Last note, Time.deltaTime is time between frames inside `Update()`, not physics steps, read docs about `Time.deltaTime` and `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

Comment: Thanks for the extra notes!! They were really useful!!

Comment: Please accept the answer, unless it did not solve your problem